# Insert time stamp in file name with extension intact

Tags: excel, vba

I get full path of an Excel file from a cell and use a function to retrieve the file name. I have final result as "abc.xlsx"

I need to insert a time stamp in the file name like "abc_02_11_19.xlsx".

I am able to generate the time stamp, the problem is appending it. The best I could think of was to remove the last five letters from the file name i.e. ".xlsx", append the time stamp and then append the ".xlsx".

The ending might also be ".xlsm", ".xlsb" or ".xls". I would need to extract everything after the dot.

Any better way to do this or if not, how best to do it elegantly?

Snippet of code, I am using-

```
oldname = FunctionToGetName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Text)

newname = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Text) & " " & oldname

newname = Replace(Replace(Replace(newname, ":", "_"), "/", "_"), "*", "_")
```

This inserts the time stamp before the file name. I need to append it after.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this with your functions as I don't know what they do. But if I'm correct, the `FunctionToGetName` will return the filename as "filename.extention" and `FileDateTime` will return the date stamp you wish to attach.

With this you can get the filename by cutting everything after the "." with `Left$(filename, InStr(oldname, ".") - 1)`. Then you can do the reverse of that and add the file extention back with `Right$(oldname, Len(oldname) - InStr(oldname, "."))`. And as per below, you can put pretty much anything in between.

```
Sub what()
Dim filename As String
Dim oldname As String

oldname = FunctionToGetName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Text)

Newname = Left$(filename, InStr(oldname, ".") - 1) & " " & FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Text) & "." & Right$(oldname, Len(oldname) - InStr(oldname, "."))
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work where file name has dot in it e.g. "file.name.xlsx"

Comment: @D_Bester This is true, and a different approach will be needed when that happens. However using dots in the filename is considered bad practise any time (because of issues like this), and might not be the case at all in OP's data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out FSO

```
Dim fso as object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oldname As String
Dim newname As String
oldname = "abc.xlsx"
newname = fso.GetBaseName(oldname) & "_" & Format(Now(), "mm_dd_yy") & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(oldname)
Debug.Print newname
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object

Comment: This also worked..it's a new solution for me..Thanks